# Using validators to constrain the acceptable domains for a db field that stores a URL?

Tags: web2py

I have a table with a db field which should store a valid URL, and I would like to limit the permitted URL entries to three or four specific domains (let's say, only google.com, yahoo.com, and bing.com are allowed).

```
... Field('f_url', type='string', requires = IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_URL()), label=current.T('URL')), ...
```

What's the best way to use validators to specify the acceptable domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `IS_MATCH` validator:

```
IS_EMPTY_OR([IS_URL(), IS_MATCH(r'google\.com$|yahoo\.com$|bing\.com$')])
```